# Type argument list cannot be empty

Tags: angular

I am running my code

```
private convertToItemsValidationTo(selectedRows: DetailsTo[]) {
if (!selectedRows || selectedRows.length === 0) {
  return;
}
(...)
itemsValidationTo.convertedVlues = new Map<>();

selectedRows.forEach(row => {

  itemsValidationTo.convertedRates.set(row.itemId, [row.value, 0]);


  }
```

And I get an error "Type argument list cannot be empty" while compiling the application on the line

> itemsValidationTo.convertedVlues = new Map<>();

, however the app itself works fine. My object looks like this:

```
export class ItemsValidationTo {
(...)
convertedValues: Map<number, [number, number]>;

}
```

What could I do on the initializing part not to get this error?

Comment: You cannot use diamond operator `<>` like in Java. You have to specify the types between `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to initialize it like this:

> itemsValidationTo.convertedVlues = new Map();

Answer (score 0):

You can make it `new Map<any>()` but that is not really nice. 
It is probably better is to figure out what type is needed, this might be done by accepting a type parameter inside the function itself or if it is always the same type by adding the type to the new statement, for example `new Map<number>()`.